# Is it possible to download the financials (data) of every US securities from websites like morning star or bloomberg?

Tags: database

I am not sure whether this question belongs here or not, but I going ask anyway, Is it possible to download the financials (data) of every US securities from websites like morningStar or Bloomberg?

Comment: Depends on how you define "financials."

Comment: @MatthewGaiser eps, free cash flow etc. The "key ratio".